# Python speech recognition very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am currently developing a smart assistant program (basically it is just listening to what the user says and based on that does something with the code). It was working fine up until today, when I switched to my laptop. The program does not print out any errors, but it also doesn't print out what I said. I'm using the [Python Speech Recognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) library version 3.8.1. Does anybody know of an alternative for this library? If yes, please try to explain how I would use it 'on the fly' (without first recording the file and then sending it to the server, more like real-time speech).

EDIT: I forgot to say it in the post, I'm using Python 3.

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import speech_recognition as sr


global x


def speech():

    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            global x
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            audio = r.listen(source)
            x = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("No clue what you said, listening again... \n")
        speech()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Listening and printing what I heard: \n')
    speech()
    print(x)
```

Comment: You say you switched to your laptop? Any chance it's a relic compared to the other machine that's working fast? Are you sure you're audio input is working on this laptop and  that Python has access to the sound source?

Comment: Well, the machine isn't anything to brag about, but I don't think it's the issue, as its job is only to record and send audio. I've checked my microphone with audacity, but I'm not sure how to check if Python has access.

Comment: Depending on your OS, `pavucontrol` can under the *recording* tab show which device Python is using while it's recording. This assume you're running PulseAudio as your main driver for the sound sources. Also, if the machine is anything newer than 2000, it shouldn't be a problem. Older CPU's might have a hard time keeping up with the processing and recording and handling the data going back and fourth. But then that's not the case.

Comment: Which API are you using btw, to do the processing?

Comment: I just checked, and it seems like it's using the correct microphone (the line even moves when I speak, so that should confirm it). The laptop is definietly not the problem, as it has a dual core CPU @ 2.0 GHz. If it's any help, I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Comment: I use google's speech API for speech detection, I will post the code in the question.

Comment: Good start, heh :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem was in the laptop's microphone. The speech recognition worked fine after I plugged in my Blue Snowball. I forced the program to use the Blue Snowball by going into `pavucontrol` and selecting the Blue Snowball under the *recording* tab.

Comment: Be sure you accept your own answer if you're satisfied with the outcome.

Comment: Yeah, I will, just gotta wait for the 18 hour delay.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be that your mic levels are either too high or too low,
in both the cases the speech_recognition would get either too less audio or too much audio to work with. Take a look at that in your system settings. It helped me, hope it helps you.