# Python 3 permission error when playing a sound file (mp3, playsound module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-playsound

The program was working fine a few days ago, and it just stopped today. Not a single letter has been changed. One of my troubleshooting steps was to remove the file 'output1.mp3' and check if it will work that way, but it didn't. Another thing is that when it wasn't printing out the error, it would continue to play just this one sound file, whether or not it said the correct thing. Here's the latest error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main3.py", line 123, in <module>
    start()
  File "main3.py", line 117, in start
    tts(say)
  File "main3.py", line 24, in tts
    play('output1.mp3')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 275 for command:
        open "output1.mp3" alias playsound_0.8842337577803419
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.
```

Here's the code that I use:

```
import boto3                               # used to 'pythonize' Amazon Polly TTS
import speech                              # speech recognition
from playsound import playsound as play    # for playing sound files
import sys                                 # basically only for exiting
#  import locator                          # for determining the location of the user based on IP address
import locator2                            # for confirming auto-detected location
#  import locator3                         # for definitely confirming auto-detection location
import question                            # module for answering any question

from datetime import datetime              # for displaying the date and time
#  from time import sleep                  # sleep (wai()t for) function
from os import popen as read               # for reading command outputs "read('COMMAND').read()"

def tts(text):
    polly = boto3.client("polly")
    spoken_text = polly.synthesize_speech(Text=str(text),
                                          OutputFormat='mp3',
                                          VoiceId='Brian')
    with open('output11.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(spoken_text['AudioStream'].read())
        f.close()
    play('output11.mp3')

def ask(query):
    question.question(query)
    response = question.answer
    print(response)
    tts(response)
    ai()

def time():
    now = datetime.now()
    print("Current date and time: ")
    print(now.strftime("%H:%M") + "\n")
    tts("It is " + now.strftime("%H:%M"))
    ai()

def weather():
    response = "Based on your IP address, I've detected that you're located in %s. Is that correct?" % locator2.city
    print(response)
    tts(response)
    speech.speech()
    if 'yes' in speech.x:
        z = read('weather "%s"' % locator2.city).read()
        print(z)
        tts(z)
        ai()
    else:
        response = 'Please say the name of the city you would like the weather information for. \n'
        print(response)
        tts(response)
        speech.speech()
        city = speech.x
        wdr = read('weather "%s"' % city).read()
        print(wdr)
        tts(wdr)
        ai()

def thank():
    response = "You're very welcome! \n"
    print(response)
    tts(response)
    ai()

def ext():
    response = "Goodbye!"
    print(response)
    tts(response)
    sys.exit()

def error():
    response = "Invalid request detected, please try again...\n"
    print(response)
    tts(response)
    ai()

def ai():
    print('Started listening - Speak!')
    speech.speech()
    spoken = speech.x

    # TODO new commands should be written above this, and their trigger words below :)
    question_words = ['?', 'what', 'where', 'when', 'who', 'how', 'why']

    if 'time' in spoken:
        time()

    elif 'weather' in spoken:
        weather()

    elif any(word in spoken for word in question_words):
        ask(spoken)

    elif 'thank' in spoken:
        thank()

    elif 'exit' or 'quit' or 'deactivate' in spoken:
        ext()

    else:
        error()

def start():
    say = "Hello! My name is Dave, and I'm your personal assistant. How may I help you today? \n"
    print(say)
    tts(say)
    ai()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ext()
```

The speech synthesizer is [Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/). By the way, I was using PyCharm as an IDE and working on Windows 10. When I switch to my Linux machine the speech recognition part breaks.

**UPDATE**: I was tweaking the code a bit and managed to fix the pyaudio error, but I got another one in the process, this time it was about permissions. Here's the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Despot/Desktop/DAv3/main3.py", line 123, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:/Users/Despot/Desktop/DAv3/main3.py", line 118, in start
    ai()
  File "C:/Users/Despot/Desktop/DAv3/main3.py", line 96, in ai
    time()
  File "C:/Users/Despot/Desktop/DAv3/main3.py", line 39, in time
    tts("It is " + now.strftime("%H:%M"))
  File "C:/Users/Despot/Desktop/DAv3/main3.py", line 21, in tts
    with open('output11.mp3', 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output11.mp3'
```

**UPDATE 2**: I have been tikering about and I've found that the issue is only present on my Windows 10 machine, the program works fine on Linux.

Comment: Is what you're showing your `main3.py` file? Which lines are 117 and 123 in your code? Start there.

Comment: Yes, that is main3.py. Lines 117 and 123 just point to the tts() function (the one I use for speech synthesis). And what bugs me the most is that it just stopped working with no apparent reason...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the absolute path (complete path) of the audio file instead of the relative path.

For example: "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/dolphin.wav" instead of just "dolphin.wav"

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

playsound libs has a windows directories in them.
If this fail only on Linux you should install playsound lib on the linux machine and then copy only the main3.py to it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that requests for clarification from the OP should only be made in the comments, as answers are reserved for... answers. You will have to wait until you gain the necessary reputation (50) to be able to comment. Until then, you're welcome to answer questions that don't need further clarifications!

Comment: I'v change it to an answer

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other, because the problem is not in the audio reproduction - that works fine - but in python refusing to write new data to a file (and in a separate question that Python's Speech Recognition library just freezes and refuses to cooperate on my linux machine, you can find that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492176/python-speech-recognition-very-slow))

Comment: Check out your traceback - right after this line: "File "main3.py", line 24, in tts", it try to access "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py" which clearly can't be access to in a linux machine since it's a windows directory. this is an error message from the playsound libraries, that means that the libraries contain bad directories and should be replaced.

Comment: Did you copied the playsound libraries from your windows machine to your linux machine ?

Comment: No, I installed playsound via pip3 on my linux machine. I was tweaking the code for a bit and managed to fix that error, but got another one. I'll post it as an update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for UPDATE2:
Copy output11.mp3 to another location and change the path to the new location:

```
with open('CHANGE-THIS-PATH', 'wb') as f:
```

Also make sure python run as administrator.

Comment: I just tried this, but no luck. I removed the file "output11.mp3" and it worked fine for the 1st write, but delivered the same error when it tried to write for the 2nd time. I even ran it from a cmd that I ran as administrator.

Comment: Does your python use the file while your trying to write it ?

Comment: I don't think it does. As I've said before - the code just decided not to work after a while. It was working fine in the past...

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the audio file from `sample.wav` to `sample`
and then run it as `playsound('sample.wav')`

Luckily It ran.
Then I came to know that previously it was stored as `sample.wav.wav`.

So let's keep your audio file name as `output.wav` and try running your audio file as:

```
playsound('output.wav.wav') # or else rename it to output and run as 
playsound('output.wav')     # likewise for other audio formats too
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the .py and .wav files to a folder less deep inside the file system.